# Fetching a user's IP through OpenShift's PHP Cart

Tags: php, ip, openshift

I cannot fetch users' IPs through the OpenShift PHP Cartridge. I've tried the X-forwarded-for, forwarded-for, remote-addr headers, but I still am unable to fetch a user's IP. All those headers are blank.

Any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try $_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];

Comment: Thanks, that helped. I used apache_get_headers(), then ['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']